# Session not starting in PHP 7.4 but the same code works in PHP 7.1 without doing any change

Tags: php, session-variables

backend.php file : where following session variables are being set

```
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $user_email;
```

Next : As I can verify in the directory /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74 the session files are getting created. After this the session suppose to be read and understood by the website frontend index.php file and for that below is the index.php code

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_email'])){

update session variable e.g., 
$user_email = $_SESSION['user_email'];

}else{
    echo "session not set"; 
}
```

but somehow the session_start() or if(isset($_SESSION['user_email'])) is not functioning hence the flow always go to else condition and it ends with "session not set"

Note: The php.ini file contains session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"